# Flash / App Engine request data encoding problem (GET works, POST fails)

Tags: actionscript-3, google-app-engine, encoding, request

I'm new to Flash and trying to communicate with an app engine server but I'm having some encoding problems.

```
var playerLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
playerLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event) { doStuff(); } );
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.q = "åäö";
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest( serverUrl );
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = requestVars;
playerLoader.load( urlRequest );
```

This does not work, gives me some encoding errors on the server side. But if I switch POST to GET it automagically works.

Any clues what's going on and how I could use POST?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Actionscript's HTTP requests will natively be encoded in UTF-8.

I have it working this way for spanish chars:

```
var url:String = "historia.php";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var now:Date = new Date();
requestVars.historia = "áóíúéñÁÓÍÚÉÑ";   
request.data = requestVars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.load(request);
```

And on the PHP side (resumed for clarity):

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if(isset($_POST['historia']) {
    $historia = mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_decode($_POST['historia']));
    $historia = filter_var($historia, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        // insert into DB...
}
```

I use `utf8_decode()` because the database is not configured with encoding `UTF-8`.

How are you handling the request on the server side? Maybe the problem lies on the server side.

Comment: Thanks! I think I might have jumped the gun with the question and the problem was else where. Got it working with POST.